# Retrieving cookie values

Tags: c#, cookies

I have a simple but confusing issue with cookies. I noticed that on some computers the behaviour is different when retrieving the cookie value. The same page has been loaded making sure that the cookie value has been set on the computers, and I was using Firefox to test with. For example, this works on my development computer:

```
string cookieName = Request.Cookies["cookieName"];
```

However, this throws an error on some other computers that require this to work instead:

```
string cookieName = Response.Cookies["cookieName"];
```

Why do I have to use Response to retrieve a cookie value on some computers and not others?

Comment: Response.Cookies *only* works when you have set cookies in the current Response to send. Request.Cookies works for *every* request after you have sent those cookies, *until* the expiration/end of browser session.

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you tried Request.Cookies["cookieName"].Value?

Comment: The Response.Cookies values are set in Page_Load and then retrieved in the click event function for a button on the same page, does this count as having sent the response? I thought a postback would require me to use Request.Cookies?

Comment: I don't know the answer but ... Can you include in your question the behavior when it is not working? ie: throws an exception, cookie value is empty, etc... :)

Comment: The issue was related to when I set the cookies in response, as Andrew pointed out.